# What font is used on this Danube Dragons T-shirt?

Tags: font-identification

I would like to know which font is used on this T-shirt of my local football team. Unfortunately they don't use it anywhere else - neither on the website nor on any other merchandise... Not sure if this is a font at all - if it isn't, I am looking for a similar one.

I tried to identify it via *WhatTheFont!* and *What Font is*, but they had troubles recognizing the letters because almost all of them touch each other...

[image: T-shirt imprint]

Comment: @ZachSaucier You're right, especially the Ds look very different :( Do you have any idea which font could have been used as a base or is similar to this?

Comment: You can look into "paint"/"painted" fonts. I don't know many off the top of my head

Comment: @ZachSaucier Ok thx, will give it a try!

Comment: I disagree with @ZachSaucier. The R A and O are the same (allowing for printing differences); D is probably an upper/lower-case variation. But you would have to do some work separating the letters for WhatTheFont to work.

Answer (score 9):

I tried to separate the letters as suggested by [Andrew Leach](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69176/what-font-is-used-on-this-danube-dragons-t-shirt?noredirect=1#comment104837_69176) and *What Font is* finally delivered the correct result :)

The font is called [**Angryblue**](http://www.whatfontis.com/Angryblue.font?text=Proud%20to%20be%20a%20Dragon!):

[image: What Font is screenshot]

Thx for your help!